# Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 3, column: 12, Syntax error. Chrome Error json file

Tags: json, google-chrome

Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 3, column: 12, Syntax error.

```
{
    "name": "invite all fb1",
    "version"; "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Here you can test the new Invite all for the new invite box in fb",
    "browser_action": { 
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRvp9.jpg

Comment: You have a ; instead of : in "version"

Comment: You could have quickly identified the issue yourself by using a JSON validation tool like JSONLint: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a syntax error in `"version"; "1.0"`. change it to `"version": "1.0",`:

```
{
    "name": "invite all fb1",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Here you can test the new Invite all for the new invite box in fb",
    "browser_action": { 
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "name": "invite all fb1",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Here you can test the new Invite all for the new invite box in fb",
    "browser_action": { 
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

Replaced `;` with `:` after version. `"version": "1.0",`